# SciDAVis 0.2.4-4 removes fitted functions upon re-opening a saved project

Tags: error-handling, scidavis

SciDAVis works fine when I make a new project. I enter data, plot it, and fit a relevant function to the graph. Then I save the project and close it. Upon re-opening the project I get an "Input function error" message reading:

{Function Name}:0

Unexpected token ";{Values of constants of the function};{Function equation} " found at position {some number}.

Where information in {} brackets denote function specific data.

After clicking OK (I get an error like the one above for each function fitted to the graph) the function(s) is gone, I can't find it's layer or see it on the graph.

The results log does retain information about the functions however.

Any assistance in solving this would be greatly appreciated!